# How do I match kafka log pattern in grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I want to parse kafka log. Here is a sample log text.

```
[2016-02-01 15:29:02,039] INFO [Replica state machine on controller 0]: Invoking state change to OnlineReplica for replicas [Topic=elk-test,Partition=0,Replica=0] (kafka.controller.ReplicaStateMachine)
[2016-02-01 15:33:02,457] TRACE [Controller 0]: checking need to trigger partition rebalance (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2016-02-01 15:33:02,458] DEBUG [Controller 0]: preferred replicas by broker Map(0 -> Map([elk-test,0] -> List(0))) (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2016-02-01 15:33:02,480] DEBUG [Controller 0]: topics not in preferred replica Map() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2016-02-01 15:58:02,447] TRACE [Controller 0]: leader imbalance ratio for broker 0 is 0.000000 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
```

I tried writing many new pattern to match the above log in grok using grok-debugger. However I failed all the time.

I would appreciate any expect would help me to find the grok pattern for the above logs. Thanks.

The pattern I tried:

```
 \[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

I want to extract **controller 0** as separate field.

Answer (score 0):

You can something like this:

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}\[(?<logger>[^\]]+)\]:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```